# Ruby on Rails Error "undefined method"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, undefined

I'm designing a simple news article app. It works perfectly in development. I'm trying to post to Heroku. Whenever I try to go to the 'new' path, which leads me to a form to create a new 'post,' I get this error in my logs:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `level' for #<Post:0x007f624eca42e0>):
```

"level" is column in my "posts" table that I use to keep track of whether the article in question will be prominently displayed or not. It works in development the way it's supposed to. 
No really sure what's going on. I've tried running rake db:migrate a few times.

Here is the full heroku log:

```
2016-10-21T22:16:02.717948+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2016-10-21T22:16:02.717866 #3] DEBUG -- : [a4723811-33bd-4c11-b62f-7c3401f77048]   User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 2016-10-21T22:16:02.719426+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-10-21T22:16:02.719357 #3]  INFO -- : [a4723811-33bd-4c11-b62f-7c3401f77048]   Rendering posts/new.html.erb within layouts/application
2016-10-21T22:16:02.728995+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-10-21T22:16:02.728898 #3]  INFO -- : [a4723811-33bd-4c11-b62f-7c3401f77048]   Rendered posts/_form.html.erb (9.2ms)
2016-10-21T22:16:02.729133+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-10-21T22:16:02.729070 #3]  INFO -- : [a4723811-33bd-4c11-b62f-7c3401f77048]   Rendered posts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (9.6ms)
2016-10-21T22:16:02.729427+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-10-21T22:16:02.729362 #3]  INFO -- : [a4723811-33bd-4c11-b62f-7c3401f77048] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
2016-10-21T22:16:02.730972+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-10-21T22:16:02.730889 #3] FATAL -- : [a4723811-33bd-4c11-b62f-7c3401f77048]   
2016-10-21T22:16:02.731067+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-10-21T22:16:02.730980 #3] FATAL -- : [a4723811-33bd-4c11-b62f-7c3401f77048] ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `level' for #<Post:0x007f624eca42e0>):
2016-10-21T22:16:02.731308+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-10-21T22:16:02.731223 #3] FATAL -- : [a4723811-33bd-4c11-b62f-7c3401f77048]     11:     <%= f.input :description, class: 'form-control' %>
2016-10-21T22:16:02.731351+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-10-21T22:16:02.731295 #3] FATAL -- : [a4723811-33bd-4c11-b62f-7c3401f77048]     12:   </div>
2016-10-21T22:16:02.731420+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-10-21T22:16:02.731356 #3] FATAL -- : [a4723811-33bd-4c11-b62f-7c3401f77048]     13:    <div class="field">
2016-10-21T22:16:02.731476+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-10-21T22:16:02.731421 #3] FATAL -- : [a4723811-33bd-4c11-b62f-7c3401f77048]     14:     <%= f.input :level, class: 'form-control' %>
 2016-10-21T22:16:02.731528+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-10-21T22:16:02.731477 #3] FATAL -- : [a4723811-33bd-4c11-b62f-7c3401f77048]     15:   </div>
2016-10-21T22:16:02.731585+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-10-21T22:16:02.731530 #3] FATAL -- : [a4723811-33bd-4c11-b62f-7c3401f77048]     16:   <div class="actions">
2016-10-21T22:16:02.731652+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-10-21T22:16:02.731585 #3] FATAL -- : [a4723811-33bd-4c11-b62f-7c3401f77048]     17:     <%= f.label :photo %> 
2016-10-21T22:16:02.731705+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-10-21T22:16:02.731648 #3] FATAL -- : [a4723811-33bd-4c11-b62f-7c3401f77048]   
2016-10-21T22:16:02.731774+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-10-21T22:16:02.731726 #3] FATAL -- : [a4723811-33bd-4c11-b62f-7c3401f77048] app/views/posts/_form.html.erb:14:in `block in_app_views_posts__form_html_erb___305077094715289752_70030112058800'
2016-10-21T22:16:02.731841+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-10-21T22:16:02.731794 #3] FATAL -- : [a4723811-33bd-4c11-b62f-7c3401f77048] app/views/posts/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_posts__form_html_erb___305077094715289752_70030112058800'
 2016-10-21T22:16:02.731917+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-10-21T22:16:02.731859 #3] FATAL -- : [a4723811-33bd-4c11-b62f-7c3401f77048] app/views/posts/new.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_posts_new_html_erb___2217823637252593740_70030112076460'
```

Here is my posts_controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy, :new, :create]

# GET /posts
# GET /posts.json
def index
@posts = Post.most_recent
end

# GET /posts/1
# GET /posts/1.json
def show
end

# GET /posts/new
def new
@post = Post.new
end

# GET /posts/1/edit
def edit
end

# POST /posts
# POST /posts.json
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      format.html { redirect_to post_path(@post), notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# PATCH/PUT /posts/1
# PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @post.update(post_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

# DELETE /posts/1
# DELETE /posts/1.json
def destroy
@post.destroy
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_post
  @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, :description, :photo, :level)
end
end
```

Here is my form that's setting off the problem (I'm using the simple_form gem):

```
<%= simple_form_for @post, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>

 <%= f.error_notification %>
 <div class="field">
  <%= f.input :title, class: 'form-control' %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
  <%= f.input :content, class: 'form-control' %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
  <%= f.input :description, class: 'form-control' %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
  <%= f.input :level, class: 'form-control' %>
 </div>
 <div class="actions">
  <%= f.label :photo %> 
 <%= f.file_field :photo %>
 <br />
 </div> 
 <div class="actions">
  <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn btn-success' %>
 </div> 
 <% end %>
```

I'm also using paperclip, fyi. Can anyone see what's going on here? I'm stumped. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the schema of the `posts` table?

Comment: > Post(id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, title: string, content: string, description: string, User_Id: integer, slug: string, photo_file_name: string, photo_content_type: string, photo_file_size: integer, photo_updated_at: datetime, level: string)

This is what it says in the console. "Level" is there and it's been working in development all day.

Comment: Might be silly. Did you run `heroku run rake db:migrate`?

Comment: Thats was my question

Comment: can you post a print out of your post model from the production console

Comment: This is from the production console. "Level" is NOT there. But I don't know what to do about it. Ahhh help!

=> Post(id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, title: string, content: string, description: string, user_id: integer

Comment: Yes, I've run heroku rake db:migrate several times

Comment: Did you create the column manually and forget to write a migration for it?